# LEFT JOIN return all rows despite GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the LEFT JOIN query to include all rows from the reviews table:

```
SELECT r.review_id, SUM(v.vote_good), SUM(v.vote_bad)
FROM reviews AS r
LEFT JOIN reviews_votes_overall AS v
ON r.review_id = v.vote_review_id
GROUP BY v.vote_review_id
ORDER BY SUM(v.vote_good)
```

Unfortunately because some reviews don't have corresponding votes, the GROUP BY is causing rows from the reviews table not to be returned.

How do I return all rows from the reviews table in this query?

Comment: You might also consider storing all votes in a single (integer) column. A good vote might be '1', and a bad vote might be '-1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY r.review_id`. When a review doesn't have any votes, `v.vote_review_id` is `NULL`. When you group by `v.vote_review_id`, all records with zero votes will be grouped into a single row in the resultset, with `review_id` as `NULL`.

```
SELECT r.review_id, SUM(v.vote_good), SUM(v.vote_bad)
FROM reviews AS r
LEFT JOIN reviews_votes_overall AS v
ON r.review_id = v.vote_review_id
GROUP BY r.review_id
ORDER BY SUM(v.vote_good)
```

Comment: It happens. Sometimes you requires a fresh pair of eyes to identify the simplest of mistakes :)